# use of commas and should I divide the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Chesterton used to say that in every child there is a recently launched universe from which there is so much to learn that we need to make a huge effort to recover the candor and the wonder of a child, the realism and the objectivity of their innocence, we need to make an effort to change our customs, to see all things as new.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if the entire sentences is a quote. If not, then personally I'd say something along the lines of:

Chesterton used to say that "In every child there is a recently launched universe, within which there is so much to learn". We need to make a huge effort to recover the wonder of a child, and find the realism and objectivity of their innocence. We need to make an effort to change our customs, to once again see all things anew.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence, as it is written, is a run-on sentence. For this reason, you would need to revise it. The sentence, up to this point, "*Chesterton used to say that in every child there is a recently launched universe from which there is so much to learn that we need to make a huge effort to recover the candor and the wonder of a child, the realism and the objectivity of their innocence*" is fine (i.e. it is not a run-on sentence). The sentence becomes a run-on sentence because you have used a comma after "innocence" and added "*we need to make an effort to change our customs, to see all things as new*." This sentence (i.e. we need to make...) is a separate sentence so you cannot connect it to the first sentence with a comma.

You can spot a run-on sentence by looking for sets of subjects and verbs. This will tell you when you when you have complete sentences (you cannot join complete sentences with a comma). Your sentence has two subjects (**Chesterton** and **we**) and two verbs (**used to** and **need**). You can correct run-ons by punctuating the sentence properly. Here is how you can fix run-on sentences:

***Run-on sentence:*** She woke up late this morning, she was late for class.

- She woke up late this morning; she was late for class. (Join the two independent clauses with a semicolon.)
- She woke up late this morning, and she was late for class. (Use a comma before the coordinating conjunction “and” to join the two independent clauses.
- She woke up late this morning. **S**he was late for class. (Separate the two independent clauses with a period.)
- She was late for class **because** she woke up late this morning, . (This sentence adds the subordinate conjunction “because” to link the two independent clauses. Notice the order of the clauses was reversed. This is, sometimes, a good way to fix a run-on because the subordinate conjunction explains the relationship between the ideas, just like using a coordinate conjunction.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This really helped.  You made me understand the problem.

Comment: You are most welcome!